# mongodb mongoid-rails unable to increment counters in a hash in embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I am using Mongoid 4.0.2 , Rails 4.2.1 amd Mongodb 2.4.8.

I have **daily_events** as an embedded document in **person** collection as shown below.

```
 class Person
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :email, type: String
   field :month, type: Date
   field :monthly_total, type: Hash, default:  {:email_open => 0, :email_click => 0, :page_view => 0}

   embeds_many :daily_events
 end

 class DailyEvent
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String

   field :day_1, type: Hash, default: -> {:email_open => 0, :email_click => 0, :page_view => 0}

   field :day_2, type: Hash, default: -> {:email_open => 0, :email_click => 0, :page_view => 0}
   ...... 
   field :day_31, type: Hash, default: -> {:email_open => 0, :email_click => 0, :page_view => 0}

   embedded_in :person
 end
```

I want to increment the value of the **email_open** in **day_1** hash. So I tried to increment the **email_open** count by running this command command:

```
Person.first.daily_events.first.inc("day_1.email_open" =>  1)
```

underneath the above mongoid command tries to do this

```
{"$inc"=>{"daily_events.$.day_1.email_open"=>1}}
```

It fails with the error below:

```
 D, [2015-04-18T16:21:51.000555 #2918] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 54.14x.1x.xxx:10xxx COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 95.6645ms
 D, [2015-04-18T16:21:51.103361 #2918] DEBUG -- :   MOPED:        54.14x.1x.xx:100xx QUERY        database=msg collection=people selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 102.4067ms
 D, [2015-04-18T16:21:51.207447 #2918] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 54.14x.1x.xxx:10xxx UPDATE       database=msg collection=people selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('552ef418646176111c000000'), "person_events._id"=>BSON::ObjectId('552ef42c646176111cc80000')} update={"$inc"=>{"person_events.$.day_1.email_open"=>1}} flags=[]
 D, [2015-04-18T16:21:51.208257 #2918] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=msg command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime:   101.6476ms
 Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #      <Moped::Protocol::Command
   @length=67
   @request_id=1085
   @response_to=0
   @op_code=2004
   @flags=[]
   @full_collection_name="msg.$cmd"
   @skip=0
   @limit=-1
   @selector={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1}
   @fields=nil>
   failed with error 10140: "Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number"
```

Comment: Try changing the line to `Person.first.daily_events.first.inc("day_1.email_open",  1)`. Could be old syntax, but I've seen that in other questions.

Comment: Or you can do it the old fashioned way and do `Person.first.daily_events.first.day_1[:email_open] += 1`

Comment: Also, try changing your hash keys from symbols to strings. I.e. `"email_open"` instead of `:email_open`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Both did not work. But even if the 2nd suggestion had worked it won't have solved my problem a I need atomic increment. for feedback on your suggestions, the 1st suggestion threw the error  **ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)** and your 2nd suggestion threw the error   **TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String from (irb):5:in `+'**.

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think having  field :day_1,  field :day_2,...etc. would be a good design. Nonetheless, it seems that mongoid doesn't care about the field type inside a Hash. That's what the Mondgoid::Document is  for. You could have something like: embeds_many :day_activities -> where this one is another Mongoid Document.

Comment: @adbeel thanks for the schema design feedback.  Previously, I thought  of **embeds_many :day_activities** in  **DailyEvent** or to simply change **DailyEvent** to now hold only one day's activity by adding   a **field for a day's date**   and making **email_open, email_click** etc standalone integer fields. But I didn't go forward with that approach because I will now need to create 30 documents  to represent each day of the month instead of just one document which the schema shown in my question has. What's your take on the implication of the 30 extra documents for each month instead of one?

Comment: The only issue I see  is that embedded documents have a limit of 16M (more or less) and I'm guessing that daily_events would grow up eventually when it accumulates activities in the upcoming years. Maybe  you could do something like this -> https://gist.github.com/adbeelitamar/4a9d4b2038042cd2afc6. Basically daily events (aka MonthlyEvents) would be in its own collection. That way you'll avoid having problems with oversizing a single document by adding too much nested documents. Good luck!